# What is Work? What does the quantity suggest intuitively?

Tags: energy, work, definition

The mathematical formula for [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29) says that work is force into displacement, but what is the philosophy behind it? I mean what does the quantity suggest?

Answer (score 0):

It is the amount of energy $E$ that must be transferred to an object through Force so that it can get displaced by some distance $s$. In completely layman's terms, the amount of energy someone must spend to do something.